# Which Bottom Bracket do i need? 107mm 41

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, press-fit

I cant´t find a Bottom Bracket for my Cube two 15 2017.
It need a 107mm x 41.
Please help me.

Comment: Need more info. Is the 107 referring to the length of a modular spindle? What cranks?

Comment: @NathanKnutson One description, but not original and not sure if correct. Crank listed as XO1 DH, probably GXP spindle. BB listed unhelpfully as "8mm drop, press fit" https://mtbdatabase.com/bikes/2017/cube/two15/2017-cube-two15-hpa-sl-27-5/

Answer (score 1):

One first piece of advice to cyclists would be to Google your bike's model name and the phrase "bottom bracket". This will often show results containing the specification. However, in this case, it's unhelpful. Cube's [current Two15](https://www.cube.eu/en/2022/bikes/mountainbike/fullsuspension/two15/cube-two15-race-275-flashwhitenblack/)'s specs (or at least, one randomly selected version of that range) do reference a RaceFace BB107.

I am not familiar with this standard. The "41" you referenced may be a reference to the diameter of the BB shell. I believe only the BB86 standard corresponds to 41mm diameter. Now, "107mm", if it refers to the BB shell width, doesn't correspond to the road or the usual MTB standard, but you seem to have a downhill bike. [This BikeRadar article](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/) says that the BB86/BB92 standard may also accommodate a 107mm wide BB shell.

You could try taking the cranks off, if able. There are often markings on the bottom bracket shell that may be obscured by the crank. If you have calipers, you could confirm the shell width and diameter (or a measuring tape might be made to work). If not confident, a bike store could do this for you, and a lot of us would be getting a store to change the BB anyway.

From there, you would need to know the diameter of your crank axle. It isn't clear what you have, from the spec I listed in the comments. This would be something probably better measured. I speculated that you might have a GXP spindle (because one version of the specs listed a SRAM crankset, and in 2017 they should have been offering GXP spindles, but I don't know how common 30mm spindles were for SRAM). A bike store would likely recognize the spindle type on sight.

I believe the cups are the same across all BB86-type BBs no matter what the shell diameter. If this is correct, you'd search for BB86 in combination with your crank axle width. Or, for example, [Wheels Mfg](https://wheelsmfg.com/bb86-92-tech)'s page will direct you to pages for Shimano, GXP, SRAM DUB, or 30mm axles.

Other Google-fu type advice could include trying to figure out what BB type Cube bikes in general use. However, there's the risk that a manufacturer might change to a different type of BB at some point (e.g. Trek popularized BB90, but they were the only one to use it and it wasn't compatible with 30mm axles, and they are changing to T47), and you don't know when that point is. Or they might use different BB types at different spec levels and you might miss this. Personally, I maintain a list of critical parts and specs in Evernote just in case I forget. I checked my own bike's BB (it's a Parlee Chebacco, PF30 BB), but without taking the cranks off, the cups' only visible markings are "SRAM DUB", which is insufficient information if I didn't remember the BB standard. (This describes a crank manufacturer and an axle type, i.e. the 28.99mm DUB axle, but not the shell type.)